# how to use searchkick to index according to some conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, searchkick

I am using searchkick and rails4.

I have an activerecord People, with attributes a,b,c. How can I do indexing only when b equals "type1", not indexing otherwise?

Currently what I know is

```
def search_data
  {
    a:a,
    b:b,
    c:c,
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/ad841210c90838c4fddbd2286091761523b27f8b/README.md#indexing):

> By default, all records are indexed. To control which records are indexed, use the `should_index?` method together with the `search_import` scope.

This should work for your case:

```
class People < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick # you probably already have this
  scope :search_import, -> { where(b: "type1") }

  def should_index?
    self.search_import # only index records per your `search_import` scope above
  end

  def search_data # looks like you already have this, too
    {
      a:a,
      b:b,
      c:c,
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Inside should_index, should it be b instead of self.search_import?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be `b`. `def should_index?` only indexes records that are returned inside the `should_index?` block. And, `self.search_import?` will call the `search_import` scope, which will only return records where `b == "type1"`, which means those are the only records that will be indexed.

Comment: Can't you just skip the search_import scope declaration and just put the logic inside should_index?

Comment: Yes, from what I can see in the code [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/384be2e254b0c48e1caefadfc8f4154d1c27b1f9/lib/searchkick/bulk_indexer.rb) and [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/3fe0141c25608e5819ccee2c9a046f2d46fdc475/lib/searchkick/process_batch_job.rb), both `search_import` and `should_index?` get called before records are indexed, so you should be able to use either one.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but a teammate came up through this question earlier today and I think the topic deserves a more detailed answer.

As far as I can tell, you have two options to control which records are indexed by searchkick:

1. At the class level, you can limit the records searchkick index by defining an ActiveRecord scope `search_import`. This scope is used, essentially, when indexing multiple records at once, like when running `searchkick:reindex` task.
2. At the instance level, you can define a `should_index?` method which gets called on every record just before indexing, it determines whether a record should be added or removed from the index.

So, if you want to index only records that have `b` equals `'type1'` you could do something like below:

```rb
class People < ApplicationRecord
  scope :search_import, -> { where(b: 'type1') }

  def should_index?
    b == 'type1'
  end
end
```

Note that returning `false` from `should_import?` will remove the record form the index as you can read [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/3fe0141c25/lib/searchkick/record_indexer.rb#L64-L69).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `:search_import` scope in `should_index?`, as seen in BigRon's answer above, you need to access the scope via `self.class.search_import`.

```
class People < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick # you probably already have this
  scope :search_import, -> { where(b: "type1") }

  def should_index?
    self.class.search_import # only index records per your `search_import` scope above
  end

  def search_data # looks like you already have this, too
    {
      a:a,
      b:b,
      c:c,
    }
  end
end
```