# How to exclude records in searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I need to exclude records from searchkick when it has less than 3 tags. Right now, my search_data function is as follow:

```
def search_data
  {
    ...
    tag_ids: tags.map(&:id)
  }
end
```

Can I do this?

```
def search_data
  return nil if tags.count < 3
  {
    ...
    tag_ids: tags.map(&:id)
  }
end
```

Or can I add some condition when I perform lookup(), so it only search records that have tag_ids array with 3 or more id? (Other than add a tag_count field and reindex everything?)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use searchkick to index according to some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564187/how-to-use-searchkick-to-index-according-to-some-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searchkick provides the ability to define a `should_index?` method that does exactly what you're looking for. Check it out [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing)!

Comment: It says "use the should_index? method together with the search_import scope." Do I need to use both? Because in the example they gave, both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: I believe that the `should_index?` method is useful for case of a single record whereas `search_import` is at a broader level, ie `User#reindex` -> `should_index?` opposed to `User::reindex` -> `search_import`.